# down service Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, distributedcache

I ran `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance` and the status is down ?

```
Service Name            Service Status Versio
                                       n Info
------------            -------------- ------
AppFabricCachingService DOWN           3 [3,3
                                       ][1,3]
```

and AppFabricCachingService in Services is disabled?

Comment: Is appfabrice service is really running? Check services console on the servers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

- Open services > find AppFabricCachingService.
- Right click and check properties,
- Change disabled to automatic
- Open SharePoint Powershell as administrator

Script

```
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService" 

$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername} 
$serviceInstance.Provision()
```

- Try to run `Use_CacheCluster`
- Run `Get-CacheHost`
- The service status should be now UP

Comment: the health analyzer continue showing Distributed cache service is not enabled in this deployment

Comment: try to click on reanalyze at the above ribbon !!

Comment: I did no avail!! :( please help

Comment: try to delete the error from health analyzer list as you delete an item from the list by going to CA > Monitoring > review problem and solution. then go back to review rule definition and find your rule that raised and click on it and from the above ribbon select run now, and checks if it 's come back or not !!